# Wolfram Alpha missing solutions to a quadratic equation over the integers?

Tags: wolfram-alpha-queries

I don't have Mathematica, but Wolfram Alpha appears to miss integer solutions to bivariate quadratic equation:

[solve over integers X^2 + 1672739 Y^2 = 4680419795530281540](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+over+integers+X%5E2+%2B+1672739+Y%5E2+%3D+4680419795530281540)

returns only two pairs of solutions and there is at least one other
solution:

```
n=1672739; m=4680419795530281540;
ve = {1279600926, -1348776};
ve[[1]]^2 + n*ve[[2]]^2 - m

(* 0 *)
```

Is this a bug in WA or Mathematica?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Works fine in *Mathematica*:

```
Solve[X^2 + 1672739 Y^2 == 4680419795530281540, {X, Y}, NonNegativeIntegers]

(*    {{X -> 1672739, Y -> 1672739},
       {X -> 1279600926, Y -> 1348776},
       {X -> 1793487071, Y -> 935471}}    *)
```

Comment: Thanks. Can I make it work in WA?

Comment: This site is about *Mathematica*, not Wolfram Alpha.

Answer (score 4):

This site is about Mathematica not WolframAlpha. Mathematica finds 12 solutions.

```
eqn = X^2 + 1672739 Y^2 == 4680419795530281540;
```

Using [`Solve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Solve.html)

```
sol = Solve[eqn, {X, Y}, Integers]

(* {{X -> -1793487071, Y -> -935471}, {X -> -1793487071, 
  Y -> 935471}, {X -> -1279600926, Y -> -1348776}, {X -> -1279600926, 
  Y -> 1348776}, {X -> -1672739, Y -> -1672739}, {X -> -1672739, 
  Y -> 1672739}, {X -> 1672739, Y -> -1672739}, {X -> 1672739, 
  Y -> 1672739}, {X -> 1279600926, Y -> -1348776}, {X -> 1279600926, 
  Y -> 1348776}, {X -> 1793487071, Y -> -935471}, {X -> 1793487071, 
  Y -> 935471}} *)

Length@sol

(* 12 *)
```

Verifying the solution

```
And @@ (eqn /. sol)

(* True *)
```

Using [`Reduce`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Reduce.html)

```
sol2 = {Reduce[eqn, {X, Y}, Integers] // ToRules}

(* {{X -> -1793487071, Y -> -935471}, {X -> -1793487071, 
  Y -> 935471}, {X -> -1279600926, Y -> -1348776}, {X -> -1279600926, 
  Y -> 1348776}, {X -> -1672739, Y -> -1672739}, {X -> -1672739, 
  Y -> 1672739}, {X -> 1672739, Y -> -1672739}, {X -> 1672739, 
  Y -> 1672739}, {X -> 1279600926, Y -> -1348776}, {X -> 1279600926, 
  Y -> 1348776}, {X -> 1793487071, Y -> -935471}, {X -> 1793487071, 
  Y -> 935471}} *)
```

The results are identical:

```
sol === sol2

(* True *)
```

Using [`FindInstance`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindInstance.html)

```
sol3 = FindInstance[eqn, {X, Y}, Integers, 20]

(* {{X -> -1793487071, Y -> -935471}, {X -> -1793487071, 
  Y -> 935471}, {X -> -1279600926, Y -> -1348776}, {X -> -1279600926, 
  Y -> 1348776}, {X -> -1672739, Y -> -1672739}, {X -> -1672739, 
  Y -> 1672739}, {X -> 1672739, Y -> -1672739}, {X -> 1672739, 
  Y -> 1672739}, {X -> 1279600926, Y -> -1348776}, {X -> 1279600926, 
  Y -> 1348776}, {X -> 1793487071, Y -> -935471}, {X -> 1793487071, 
  Y -> 935471}} *)
```

The results are identical:

```
sol === sol3

(* True *)
```

**EDIT:** WolframAlpha finds the three underlying solutions (each has four sign variations) if you restrict it to positive integers.

```
WolframAlpha["Solve over positive integers X^2+1672739 
  Y^2 = 4680419795530281540"]
```

[image]